# Async self-closing helpers with Dust.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dust.js

I've been trying out Dust.js recently because it supports asynchronous helpers but I've found a case where this does not seem to be so.

For example, given the following Dust template:

```
<ul>
  {#getResults}
    <li>{#isResultNew"}*New*{/isResultNew} {message}, {#formatResultDate format="d/m/y" /}</li>
  {/getResults}
</ul>
```

If the `formatResultDate` helper is synchronous then it's no problem, I can write out the date:

```
function formatResultDate(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  ...
  return chunk.write(value)
}
```

However, if the template were asynchronous - using a promise - then nothing will be output:

```
function formatResultDate(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  ...
  return Promise.resolve(date).then(value => chunk.write(value))
}
```

I can work around this limitation by supplying a tag body (`{#formatResultDate format="d/m/y"}{.}{/formatResultDate}`) but it's not quite the behaviour I'd expect.

I'm aware that async self-closing tags may not be possible; delving into the source code I found [this comment](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/blob/3fc12efd153433a21fd79ac81e8c5f5d6f273a1c/dist/dust-core.js#L936-L938) but I don't really understand what it means and I haven't yet found any further explanation in the documentation or searching.

Comment: From what i read in the dust code, can you try simply "return Promise.resolve(date)" instead of "return Promise.resolve(date).then(value => chunk.write(value))". `reference` seem to be re-entering and reach https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/blob/3fc12efd153433a21fd79ac81e8c5f5d6f273a1c/dist/dust-core.js#L762 with the result of the promise. (I am not a dust user tough)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `{formatResultDate}` to execute the helper as a reference-- a self-closing helper has no body to render.

Additionally, a helper should either return a value or return the modified chunk-- it shouldn't both write to a chunk and then return some non-chunk value.

Just return the promise itself and Dust will do the rest.

---

Update based on your comment:

There are two types of helpers in Dust. If you include your helper function as part of your context it is a "context helper". If you attach it to the `dust.helpers` object it is a "global helper".

The comment you linked (which I wrote) indicates that **global** helpers can self-close. `{@formatResultDate/}` will output its return value into the template. Context helpers, however, can be accessed either as references or as block sections (although as you mentioned, you cannot pass parameters to a reference). Because Dust does not try to render sections with no body, context helpers follow those semantics.

Since you need to pass parameters, you have a couple options.

1) You can attach your helper to the `dust.helpers` object and access it like `{@formatResultDate date=myDate /}`. The helper can return a Promise and the value of that Promise will be output into the template. More info: [Dust Helpers](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/dust-helpers/) (see the Adding New Helpers section)

2) You can handle Promises the old-school way, just like everyone did before Dust 2.7, by using `chunk.map`. This function signals to Dust that your chunk is asynchronous. To do this, look at the section of the [Context Helpers](http://www.dustjs.com/guides/context-helpers/) guide named "Asynchronous context helpers". You would write something like this:

```
"formatResultDate": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
  return chunk.map((chunk) => Promise.resolve(date).then(chunk.end));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm afraid my example was oversimplified, the helper in question requires parameters. Your answer is definitely still useful to know though =]

Comment: I have added more info to my answer to fit your use case.

Comment: Thank you again for your detailed response. I'd made the assumption that context helpers had the same semantics as global helpers. In this situation I would prefer them to be so, so I have implemented a solution based on your example. Thanks.